# How to get response time from command PING without unit ms?

Tags: batch-file, ping

I wanted to know if it's possible to get the ping in a variable without "ms" at the end and be able to make some multiplication with the variable.

My actual code:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL :ping google.com
SET PING1=%ms%
ECHO %ping1%
GOTO :EOF

:ping
SET ms=Error
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims==" %%i IN ('ping.exe -n 1 %1 ^| FIND "ms"') DO SET ms=%%i
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ms` to your delims, `FOR /F "tokens=4 delims==ms" ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude !

Answer (score 1):

To fix your existing code, you could just `set "ms=%ms:ms=%"` to strip the "ms" out of the value.

I learned a [nifty method of pinging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37600304/1683264) not long ago that might suit your needs.

```js
@echo off & setlocal
call :ping www.google.com ms

echo %ms%
goto :EOF   

:ping <host/IP> <return_var>
setlocal
set "responsetime=Error"
for /F %%I in (
    'wmic path win32_pingstatus where "address='%~1'" get responsetime /value'
) do 2>NUL set /a %%I
endlocal & set "%~2=%responsetime%" & goto :EOF
```

Comment: I don't know how to make your code works


Edit : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zbQCK6sz)

Comment: @Hydroo Sorry, I fixed it.